# String replace all that not mach regex

Tags: javascript, regex

This is my javascript regex: `/^(\d+\.?\d{0,2})$/` My target is to replace all inputs according to it. Is that possible? Example:

```
123a.12 => 123.12
aaa12aa => 12
12.aaa13 => 12.13
12.aaa => 12
12.555 => 12.55
12.... => 12
12.    => 12
12.35.12.14 => 12.35
12.aaa.2.s.5 => 12.25
```

I was using `str.replace(/^(\d+\.?\d{0,2})$/, '')` but with no success

Comment: `string.replace(/[^\d.]/g, "")` - Replace any character that is not a digit or a period

Comment: You can do it using `parseFloat('12.aaa13'.replace(/[^\d.]/g, '')).toFixed(2);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can replace the first `.` with a placeholder, I have used `|`. Then, remove any characters that are not digits or the placeholder. Finally, replace your placeholder with `.`. Then, remove anything past 2 decimal places:

```js
const num = (s) => {
  const clean = s.replace(".", "|").replace(/[^\d|]/g, '').replace('|', '.');
  
  return parseInt(clean * 100) / 100;
}

const tests = [
  "123a.12",
  "aaa12aa",
  "12.aaa13",
  "12.aaa",
  "12.555",
  "12....",
  "12.",
  "12.35.12.14",
  "12.aaa.2.s.5"
];

tests.forEach(test => console.log(test + " => " + num(test)));
```

Comment: @IntoTheDeep In my example it works as expected. It's the 5th element in my `tests` array.

Comment: What if i type e which is valid input for number?

Comment: @IntoTheDeep "e" would be removed from the input string. Do you want to accept "e" as a valid number to pull out of the string?

Comment: This is not working because when I am typing into input, it deletes first dot

Comment: @IntoTheDeep If you are filtering an input as the user types, that's a different question. This only handles a complete string.

Comment: @IntoTheDeep I believe this answers the original question. If you post a new question on how to apply it to an input or update the question, I will be happy to answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195680/discussion-between-frobinsonj-and-intothedeep).

Answer (score 2):

Do in in steps: first replace anything that is not number, then trim `.`:

```js
function getNum(input, expected){
  num = input
    .replace(/[^\d.]/g, '')
    .replace(/\.+$/, '')
    .replace(/^\.+/, '');
    
  console.log(input + ' => ' + num + ' | ' + expected)
}

getNum('123a.12', '123.12');
getNum('aaa12aa', '12');
getNum('12.aaa13', '12.13');
getNum('12.aaa', '12');
getNum('abcd.12', '12');
getNum('abcd.efg.12.abcd.efg', '12');
```

Comment: I must have only two decimals after comma

Answer (score 1):

One option for your current examples is to use an alternation to match either not a digit, dot or whitespace char or match a dot followed by 1+ non digits and assert that is does not end on a digit.

```
[^\d.\s]+|\.[^\d]+(?!\d)\b
```

```js
[
  "123a.12",
  "aaa12aa",
  "12.aaa13",
  "12.aaa "
].forEach(str => console.log(str.replace(/[^\d.\s]+|\.[^\d]+(?!\d)\b/g, '')));
```

**Edit after the updated question**

To get the values without trailing dots and 2 decimals, you could make use of [replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) and the callback function.

First replace all not digits and dots with an empty space using `[^\d.]+`

The use a pattern to get the first dot and 2 following digits. Use capturing groups to return the match that you want by checking the value of the any other group than the first.

```
^(\d+)(?:\.+|(\.)\.*(\d)\.*(\d).*)$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/8tqYZD/1)

```js
strings = [
  "123a.12",
  "aaa12aa",
  "12.aaa13",
  "12.aaa",
  "12.555",
  "12....",
  "12.",
  "12.35.12.14",
  "12.aaa.2.s.5"
].map(str => {
  return str
    .replace(/[^\d.]/g, '')
    .replace(/^(\d+)(?:\.+|(\.)\.*(\d)\.*(\d).*)$/, function(m, g1, g2, g3, g4) {
      return undefined !== g2 ? g1 + g2 + g3 + g4 : g1;
    });
});

console.log(strings);
```

Comment: `12.aaa` should be just `12`, not `12.`

Comment: @Justinas You are right, I have updated the answer.

Comment: I must have only two decimals after comma

Comment: @Justinas I have added an edit to reflect the updated values.

Answer (score 0):

This should handle all cases, unless there are two periods in a row.

```
let myString = 'test1.0.test'
myStr.replace(/[^\d.-]/g,'').replace(/[^\d.-]|\.$/g, '')
// 1.0
```